# wp_kses() doesn't allow underbar

Tags: php, html, wordpress

In wordpress, wp_kses() function removes html tags and attributes except allowed ones:

```
$post = "<p class="sample">This is a picture.<img src="sample.jpg" height="333"/><br/></p>";
$allowed = array(
   "p" => array(),
   "img" => array(
        "src" => array()
    ),
);
echo wp_kses($post, $allowed);
> <p>This is a picture.<img src="sample.jpg"/></p>
```

However, I cannot allow attributes including an underbar:

```
$post = "<p class="sample">This is a picture.<img src="sample.jpg" height="333" under_bar="some" /><br/></p>";
$allowed = array(
   "p" => array(),
   "img" => array(
        "src" => array(),
        "under_bar" => array()
    ),
);
echo wp_kses($post, $allowed);
> <p>This is a picture.<img src="sample.jpg"/></p>
```

I know I should use another names, but I want to know the solution for using underbar.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure there is no solution to this, at least not using `wp_kses()` in its form. If you take a look at [the code](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.4.2/src/wp-includes/kses.php#L0), you will find out that WordPress, at a [certain point](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.4.2/src/wp-includes/kses.php#L821), parses the attribute `under_bar="some"` with this to get the attribute name and, later, its value:

```
if ( preg_match('/^([-a-zA-Z:]+)/', $attr, $match ) ) {
    $attrname = $match[1];
    $working = $mode = 1;
    $attr = preg_replace( '/^[-a-zA-Z:]+/', '', $attr );
}
```

To put it clearly, it's using a regex to get the attribute name, and it does not accept an underscore. As a result, it goes on thinking your attribute is called `under` and can't find it in the allowed tags list (and even if it found it, the rest would probably not work having gotten the name wrong).

The easiest thing to do would probably just using a dash. You could try a clever use of filter hooks to do something different with `wp_kses()`, but I think it would be basically like rewriting the whole thing.

Comment: Thank you! I understood why I can't use an underscore.
Do you know what happens if using attributes not defined by W3C? ( I know it's another question though)

Comment: As far as I know, nothing much, except your page won't be valid HTML (but will most probably work anyway). Definitely go for another answer though, or better see if it's already answered somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

It is quite Possible.  Here is an example;

```
    <?php

                            $row_content = '<i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i>';
                            $allowed_html = array(

                                'i' => array(
                                    'class' => array(),
                                    'href'  => array(),
                                    'rel'   => array(),
                                    'title' => array(),
                                    'aria-hidden' => array()
                                )
                            );

                            ?>

                            <?php echo wp_kses( $row_content, $allowed_html ); ?>
```